# Загрузить с api список с помощью Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, retrofit2, model-view

Уважаемые, умудренные опытом стекоуверфлоучане, вопрос: почему крашится приложение? понял, что с ссылкой что-то не так, а что именно понять не могу

```
class RetroInstance {

    companion object {

        private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10/"

        fun getRetroInstance(): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
    }
}

interface RetroServiceInterface {

    @GET
    fun getJokeList(): Call<List<JokeModel>>
}


class JokeListAdapter(val activity: Activity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<JokeListAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

    private var jokeList: List<JokeModel>? = null

    fun setJokeList(jokeList: List<JokeModel>?){
        this.jokeList = jokeList
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): JokeListAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.joke_list_raw, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JokeListAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(jokeList?.get(position)!!, activity)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        if(jokeList == null) return 0
        else return jokeList?.size!!
    }

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        val jokeText = view.joke_text_view

        fun bind(data: JokeModel, activity: Activity) {
            jokeText.text = data.joke
        }
    }
}
```

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var recyclerAdapter: JokeListAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    initRecyclerView()
    initViewModel()
}

private fun initRecyclerView() {
    jokeListRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerAdapter = JokeListAdapter(this)
    jokeListRecyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter

}

private fun initViewModel(){
    val vieModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
    vieModel.getLiveDataObserver().observe(this, Observer {
        if (it != null){
            recyclerAdapter.setJokeList(it)
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, " Error is getting list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
    vieModel.makeApiCall()
}
```

}

В Logcat выдает вот такое

--------- beginning of crash
2021-09-14 14:35:30.322 7162-7162/com.example.chacknorrisfromapi

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chacknorrisfromapi, PID: 7162
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chacknorrisfromapi/com.example.chacknorrisfromapi.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing either @GET URL or @Url parameter.
        for method RetroServiceInterface.getJokeList
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing either @GET URL or @Url parameter.
        for method RetroServiceInterface.getJokeList
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:43)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:210)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:67)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:26)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy0.getJokeList(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.chacknorrisfromapi.viewmodel.MainActivityViewModel.makeApiCall(MainActivityViewModel.kt:27)
        at com.example.chacknorrisfromapi.MainActivity.initViewModel(MainActivity.kt:42)
        at com.example.chacknorrisfromapi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
            ... 11 more
2021-09-14 14:35:30.350 7162-7162/com.example.chacknorrisfromapi I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7162 SIG: 9
```

Comment: на вкладке logcat должна быть причина падения

Comment: А зачем вы обрывки кода приложили? Покажите где и как запрос осуществляете.

Comment: добавил. инициализирую ViewModel в MainActivity

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас запрос GET а откуда вы это запрашиваете не указано:

```
@GET("endpoint_name")
fun getJokeList(): Call<List<JokeModel>>
```

в итоге у вас получится итоговый адрес:

```
"https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10/endpoint_name"
```

а сейчас у вас вероятнее всего запрос летел сюда:

```
"https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10/"
```

[вот тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/520544/) описано хорошо как работать с Retrofit2 на котлине. Либо укажите в качестве параметра к методу:

```
fun getJokeList(@Url url:String): Call<List<JokeModel>>
```

Comment: Но ведь у `GET` как раз дефолтное значение урла есть и можно его не указывать...

Comment: О, почитал доку)) Url в `@GET` можно не указывать только если первым параметром помеченного метода идет строка, помеченная аннотацией `@Url`

Comment: Missing either GET URL or Url parameter. да и по ошибке тоже указано это)